# I have compiled the 3.8.2 kernel and the fan doesn't stop after resume from suspend 12.04.02 LTS xubuntu

Tags: kernel, xubuntu, fan

Kernel config for HP 6730b notebook

I can't figure out what I did that's causing this issue.
This is xubuntu latest version 12.04.02 LTS

Link for kernel config: http://pastebin.com/AuYWdNDR

Any sugestions?

Thank you for any help.

sensors

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  (crit = +256.0°C)
temp2:        +43.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)
temp3:        +43.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp4:        +31.4°C  (crit = +110.0°C)
temp5:       +100.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +39.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +37.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

ACPI Config:

```
  0.443879] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 13 devices
[    0.443881] ACPI: ACPI bus type pnp unregistered
[    2.439310] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for AC is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
[    2.439390] ACPI: AC Adapter [AC] (on-line)
[    2.439463] ACPI: Sleep Button [SLPB]
[    2.439537] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID]
[    2.439575] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    2.439649] ACPI: Fan [FAN0] (off)
[    2.439693] ACPI: Fan [FAN1] (off)
[    2.439731] ACPI: Fan [FAN2] (off)
[    2.439773] ACPI: Fan [FAN3] (off)
[    2.439811] ACPI: Fan [FAN4] (off)
[    2.439861] ACPI: Requesting acpi_cpufreq
[    2.441224] ACPI: acpi_idle registered with cpuidle
[    2.454302] ACPI: Thermal Zone [DTSZ] (78 C)
[    2.470887] ACPI: Thermal Zone [CPUZ] (81 C)
[    2.474253] ACPI: Thermal Zone [SKNZ] (63 C)
[    2.486164] ACPI: Thermal Zone [BATZ] (30 C)
[    2.491937] ACPI: Thermal Zone [FDTZ] (25 C)
[    2.555275] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for battery is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
[    2.555281] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    2.555329] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for battery is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
[    2.555335] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT1] (battery absent)
[    3.753101] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x0000000000000005) is beyond end of object (20121018/exoparg2-418)
[    3.753109] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0._DOD] (Node ffff88013aa322f8), AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT (20121018/psparse-537)
[    3.753116] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Evaluating _DOD (20121018/video-1163)
[    3.755247] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    4.103636] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[    4.113621] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[    4.436787] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[    4.441624] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[   12.240143] parport_pc 00:09: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
[   12.434379] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   12.434387] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   12.434391] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   12.434394] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   12.434395] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   12.434398] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[  260.354206] tg3 0000:85:00.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  263.508180] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: power state changed by ACPI to D3hot
[  263.524145] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  263.540109] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  263.540193] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  263.540275] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  263.540317] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.7: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  263.556104] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.2: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  263.556188] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  263.556271] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[  263.556663] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[  263.700482] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[  263.714676] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[  263.876133] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  263.876205] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  263.876275] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1a.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  263.892060] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.7: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  263.912033] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
[  263.928473] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  263.928540] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  263.928608] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  263.944058] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  264.112308] tg3 0000:85:00.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
[  264.358813] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[  264.364213] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[  264.371521] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
[  264.374199] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
```

Comment: Why has this question been marked as 'off-topic'?

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue... Disabling and enabling modules I found the problem to be in:

I disabled 
**ACPI -> FAN** Module

All looks to be working well now.

Comment: So, how did you fix the problem, exactly? Was that module just not selected for compilation?

Comment: Yes, I just removed the selection from the module to avoid it being compile or placed has a module.

Comment: You may want to edit your answer to clarify that you solved this by *disabling* that module, as people reading your answer will probably think you *enabled* it.